# Get HTML DOM with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tree

CSS can apply styles in elements through one ID, class or pseudo-selector, but I would like to get the HTML tree, something like in javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var div = document.getElementsByTagName ("div");

        div[0].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        div[0].style.padding = "20px";
    }
</script>
```

So for example:

```
<style type = "text/css">
    div[0] { /* Wrong but i tried :( */
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>

<div >
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

I'm tired of assign IDs to millions and millions of elements; is there a way to do this?

Comment: You want just the first `<div>`?

Comment: [1]. What you ask cannot be done with CSS alone if you don't help a bit with selectors. If there are "millions" of elements, JavaScript may not be a good idea either.

[2]. Why do you want to assign IDs to so many elements? Maybe some other kind of selector (e.g. class or maybe descendant along with something else) will do the trick.

[3]. You won't add the IDs or whatever by hand so what's the problem? :-)

Comment: You shouldn't be using a million IDs; just put classes on the elements you need to style differently. You could put a class "first" on the first div and just use that selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nth-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html)

> The :nth-child() and :nth-of-type() pseudo-classes allows you to
>   select elements with a formula.
>
> The syntax is `:nth-child(an+b)`, where you replace `a` and `b` by numbers
>   of your choice. For instance, `:nth-child(3n+1)` selects the 1st, 4th,
>   7th etc. child.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you could use:

```
body > div:first-child {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Which would match the first div in the `<body>` of the document, but I don't think that's what you're really after because that wouldn't be all that useful.

I think you're better off just using classes as they're supposed to be used rather than assigning IDs to lots of elements. In general, I find that I usually only assign IDs to the "page layout" elements (i.e. the elements that define the overall structure of the page) and then just use classes for everything else. It never really gets all that unwieldy...

Answer (score 1):

If you knew the type of element you had (as in your example) and if CSS3 was an option you could use:

```
div div:first-of-type {
   ....
}
```

It won't work in IE though. See [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_support) for details. If you don't know the type of the subelement, it won't work either. *:first-of-type is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly just use `div:first-child`.

Comment: That would match the first `<div>` that was a child of *any other* element. e.g. with `<div><div>this one</div></div>` it would match the inner `<div>` because it's the first child of the outer `<div>`.